# Imaginary part of this integral

Tags: definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I'm reading a [physics paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.02128) and there is one step involving the imaginary part of an integral that I cannot reproduce (eq 23). The integral is
$$I=\int_0^1 dx\frac{1}{\Big[xa^2+(1-x)b^2-x(1-x)c^2-i\epsilon\Big]^{3/2}},$$
where all parameters are real and $a,\,b,\,\epsilon>0$. They claim that the imaginary part of this integral is

$$\text{Im}\{I\}=\frac{2\pi}{ab}\Big[\delta(c-a-b)+\delta(c+a+b)\Big].$$

I have no clue how to get that, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hm, the authors _do_ skip a few steps don't they?

Comment: You could try the [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) with something like$$t = \frac{\sqrt{c^2x^2+(a^2-b^2-c^2)x+b^2-i\epsilon} - \sqrt{b^2-i\epsilon}}x$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just plug this integral into some computer algebra system and get

$$I = \frac{2}{a^4 + b^4 + c^4 - 2(a^2 b^2 + a^2 c^2 + b^2 c^2) + 4i\epsilon c^2}\left[\frac{b^2-a^2-c^2}{\sqrt{a^2-i\epsilon}} + \frac{a^2-b^2-c^2}{\sqrt{b^2-i\epsilon}}\right].$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal, the imaginary part is provided by the first factor. Its denominator can be written as

$$[c^2-(a+b)^2][c^2-(a-b)^2]+4i\epsilon c^2.$$

If $c^2 = (a-b)^2$, the terms in square brackets in $I$ cancel each other. In the vicinity of $c^2 = (a+b)^2$

$$I = -2\frac{a+b}{ab}\frac{1}{c^2 - (a+b)^2 + i0},$$ and you get two delta functions by the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem. Although it seems the prefactor will be $\frac{\pi}{ab}$, not $\frac{2\pi}{ab}$.

Comment: Excellent. You are also right with the prefactor. Indeed, I had noticed that in eq 24 of the paper there was a missing $2$ if eq 23 was correct. Thank you very much.